# If a set has finite outer measure, why can you find a countable number of sets that cover it?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $μ: S \to [0, \infty]$ be a set function defined on a collection $S$ of subsets of a
>   set $X$ and $\bar{\mu}: M \to [0, \infty]$ the Caratheodory measure induced by $μ$. Let $E$ be a subset of $X$ for which $μ^* (E) < \infty$. Since $μ^* (E) < \infty$, there is a cover of $E$ by a collection $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of sets in $S$ for which
>   $\sum μ(E_k)<μ^*(E)+\epsilon$.

($μ^*$ is the outer measure induced by $μ$)

Why does the sequence $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ exist?

Comment: added to the post

Comment: What is your definition of the outer measure induced by $\mu$?

Comment: it is stated in the first sentence. Let μ: S -> [0, oo] be a set function defined on a collection S of subsets of a set X

Comment: Yes. Added to the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, I know what $\mu$ is. I was wondering how you define the outer measure induced by $\mu.$ When I took measure theory I learned one way to define it, but I think your definition must be different.

Comment: I see. It is defined as the inf of all possible countable cover of E i.e. inf $\Sigma \mu^* (E_n)$

Comment: Oh. That's the definition I'm familiar with. But in that case I don't understand why your question is a question. If $\epsilon$ is positive (it is, isn't it?), then $\mu^*(E)+\epsilon$ is strictly greater than $\mu^*(E)$ which is the infimum $\Sigma\mu(E_k).$ Being greater than the infimum of $\sum\mu(E_k)$ it must of course be greater than some particular value of $\sum\mu(E_k)$ so what's the problem?

Comment: In other words by definition, if the outer measure is finite and $0 < \epsilon$ then there must be a countable cover of $E$ with measure less than $u^*(E) + \epsilon$?  That cover is exactly the sequence whose existence you were wondering at!

Comment: Yes, I did realize that after answering @bof's question. I am new to the material and scrambling to make sense of it, but now I get it. Thanks!